# How can I lock down USB Stick access on Linux workstation?

Tags: linux, permissions, security, usb, usb-drive

I have a set of Linux workstations that only *approved* users should be plugging in *approved* USB storage devices. How can I restrict mounting new USB devices to certain groups? And is there a way to reject unrecognised devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to look into a piece of software called [USBGuard](https://dkopecek.github.io/usbguard/).  It's designed specifically for handling this.  Unfortunately it's not pre-packaged for many distros, but it is pretty easy to build locally and you probably already have most if not all of the dependencies installed on the systems in question.

A custom solution is also possible, but ironically your best reference on how to do that is probably also USBGuard.